# Which school of linguistics is the most related to computational linguistics and NLP?

Tags: computational-linguistics, cognitive-linguistics, systemic-functional, structural-linguistics

I heard that there are different schools of linguistics: functional, cognitive, and structural/generative/formal.

I was wondering which schools the following books belong to:

- Essentials of Linguistics by Anderson
- Study of Linguistics, by Yule
- Linguistics: An Introduction, by Radford
- An Introduction to Languages, by Fromkin

Which school is the most related to, helpful for, or benefits computational linguistics and NLP?

Thanks.

Comment: Function and cognitive linguistics aren't radically different; structuralism is radically different from generative grammar. Your notions of "school" and the supposed strictness of divisions between them don't line up with actual practice.